# How do I make running a JUnit test in eclipse behave the same as running the Maven test on the command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, maven-3

I'm using Eclipse Oxygen for Java developers on Mac OS.  I have imported my Maven projects into the IDE.  Normally, at the command line, when I run a test, I'll run something like

```
mvn test -Dtest=UserServiceTest
```

In addition to running the "test" goal, this will also execute some custom code I have in the "process-resources" and "test-compile" goals.  However, when I run my test in the Eclipse IDE (by right clicking on the class name in the package explorer, selecting "Run" and then selecting "JUnit Test"), I notice these other goals aren't run.

Is there a way to globally set up my project so that when I run a JUnit test, it automatically behaves like typing the command above?  I realize I could individually edit the run configuration for each test, but since I have hundreds, this would take a lot of work and I'd have to do it each time I crated a new test.  It would be great if there were some global way to set up Eclipse to do ti for me.

Comment: maybe run as maven build will help you out. maven and eclipse does not work well together .. so i suggest to eighter run your tests with maven(command line or maven build) or find another solution for setting up your tests maybe @BeforeClass helps you out?

Comment: Yeah but running Mvaen builds at the command line doesn't allow for setting breakpoints and easy torubleshooting, unless there is anotehr (free) IDE out there that can simplify all this.

Comment: You can use the `mvnDebug` command to get a debuggable Maven session you can attach your debugger to.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Eclipse has **no such** built-in workspace or project **settings/preferences** and I do not know any plug-in for the desired feature.

The so-called [***Launch Configuration Templates/Prototypes***](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debug/Plan/Launch_Configuration_Templates) (see also [Eclipse bug 41353](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=41353)) are currently being developed and are expected to be shipped with [Eclipse Photon on June 27, 2018](https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NWI2cXM4MHFzc2IzbHRvYWZhMjVmajJnbzkgZ2NoczdubTRudnBtODM3NDY5ZGRqOXRqbGtAZw).

Consider changing your tests so that they can be run **on a local machine without additional parameters**, e. g. via `@BeforeClass` (JUnit 4) or `@BeforeAll` (JUnit 5).

No solution, but tips how to avoid a few mouse clicks in this context:

- To open and **to edit a launch configuration, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>** and click or choose the *Run* button or a launch configuration menu item.
- Use the [***Eclipse Runner***](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-runner) plug-in.

Comment: Regarding, "Consider changing your tests so that they can be run on a local machine without additional parameters", taht isn't possible, which is why I posed the question.

Comment: @Dave Unfortunately, the changes of Eclipse Bug 41353 have not yet been applied. As soon they have been applied you can test it in the (nightly Integration Build)[http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/] before the release on June 27, 2018.